# Get the Hostname of VM on hyper-v (given VMname) using powershell

Tags: .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

My Hyper-v has virtual machines. Hyper-v knows only VM names . I want to extract hostname  (which we get by running the 'hostname' command on cmd in virtual machine)  on hyper-v , using powershell .

Answer (score 4):

One way is to fetch the IP address of the VM and from that you can query for the hostname. I have used single command to find the hostname as:

```
$VMName = "TestVMName"
$host_name = ((Get-VM | where { $_.Name -eq $VMName }) | Select -ExpandProperty NetworkAdapters).ipaddresses[0] | ForEach-Object {([system.net.dns]::GetHostByAddress($_)).hostname }
```

Make sure your VM is discoverable in the network.

Comment: This only works if the VM is ON.  At an OFF state, this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You do have integration components installed on the guest? If you don't, install those ASAP. After the IC are up to date, you can query the host info from VM's registry like so,

```
gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters'
HostName                           : hyperv100.contoso.local
HostingSystemEditionId             : 8
...
PhysicalHostName                   : hyperv100
PhysicalHostNameFullyQualified     : hyperv100.contoso.local
VirtualMachineName                 : guest101

(gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters').PhysicalHostName
hyperv100

(gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters').PhysicalHostNameFullyQualified
hyperv100.contoso.local
```

In addition, read an article that describes the [IC registry keys](http://www.virtuatopia.com/index.php/Understanding_and_Installing_Hyper-V_Integration_Services).

Comment: That's sort of the opposite of what the original questioner was asking for I think

Comment: As Rohan said do you have any answer for this.. My Hyper-v has virtual machines. I want to extract hostname (which we get by running the 'hostname' command on cmd in virtual machine) on hyper-V. But on my Hyper-V I can find only HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest key and not HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Virtual Machine\Guest\Parameters I have installed integration component on every VM.

Comment: @AccessDenied A Hyper-V guest might have a name that's got *nothing* to do with the actual guest hostname. Thus, the solution is to query guests if they are hosted on particular Hyper-V node and use that information to build a list of guests.